# Nested Portlet Serialization

Tags: jquery, nested, portlet

Does anyone have a link to a good tutorial on nesting portlets and serializing the data?

i am trying to create a jQuery drag and drop tool where users can manage fleet -> country -> port data.  For example the second fleet consists of X countries and those countries have X ports inside of them.  I have the drag and drop functionality working as well as the connect with so you can only drag countries to countries and ports to ports.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this plugin.  I'm pretty sure it does everything you need.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/portal